# Ajuda para enviar dados do PHP para o DB

Tags: php, mysql

Sou novo na área de programação e gostaria de uma ajuda
Montei uma pagina para inserir datas em 4 campos e preciso que essas datas sejam armazenadas no DB
E meio que não sei e estou com dificuldade para montar...alguem pode me ajuda?

Outra coisa preciso mostrar essa data depois na mesma pag...e não sei se fiz certo...está comentado para não dar erro na pagina..

Obs: montei a pag em um arq ctp e a função da pag chama em um controller

**função na controller:**

```
   public function desligamentocliente()
{
    $this->set( "titulo_da_pagina", "Desligamento de Cliente");
    $idCliente = ( isset( $this->request->params['pass'][0] ) ) ? $this->request->params['pass'][0] : 0;


       //$this->verifica_ausencia_dados( $this->request->data['idCliente'] );
        $this->loadModel( "DesligamentoCliente" );

                   $connect = mysql_connect('nome_do_servidor', 'nome_de_usuario', 'senha');
                    $db = mysql_select_db('nome_bo_banco_de_dados');
                    $query_select = "SELECT login FROM usuarios WHERE login = '$login'";

       $dados = $this->DesligamentoCliente->find( "list", array( "conditions" => array(
            "_esc_codigo" => $idCliente )));
        /*if ($dados['Desligamentos']['id'] ='' ) {
           echo "Data": $dados;
        } else {
            if ($dados['Desligamentos']['id'] == "" || $dados['Desligamentos']['id'] = null) {
            echo "Data não cadastrada";
            }
        }*/

}
```

Já agradeço a ajuda o/

Comment: Comece bem não use as funções mysql_x, use o mysqli_x ou pdo. Cadê o insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa noite,

Ja que esta começando , comece aprendendo sobre o PDO o mysqli , fica mais facil.

No seu codigo , esta faltando o insert dos dados , essas 4 datas você pega de um formulario onde alguem as informa?

Vamos supor que sim. ,entao você faria o insert :

```
function conexao(){

    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpass = "1234";

    try {

        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=crm',  $dbuser, $dbpass);
        $pdo -> setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );
        $pdo->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");//corrige os acentos na hora de gravar no BD
    } catch(Exception $e) {

        echo 'Erro na conexao: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Funcao para inserir :

```
function inserirDatas($pdo){
    try {
                $data_1 = $_POST['data_1'];
                $data_2 = $_POST['data_2'];
                $arr = array();
                $sql = 'INSERT INTO suaTabela(campo1,campo2)VALUES(:data_1,:data_2)';
                $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                $dados = array(
                    ':data_1' => $data_1,
                    ':data_2' => $data_2
                );

                $stmt-> execute($dados);
                $linha = $stmt->rowCount();
                    if($linha == 1){

                        $arr['id'] = $stmt = $pdo->lastInsertId();
                        $arr['retorno'] = 1;
                    }else{
                        $arr['retorno'] = 0;
                    }

                $conexao = desconecta($conexao);
            } catch(Exception $e) {
                $resultado = 'Erro ao inserir os dados no banco: ' . $e->getMessage();
                $conexao = desconecta($conexao);
            }

return $arr;

}
```

Aqui na função , ela retorna 1 caso tenha obtido sucesso ao gravar os dados e 0 caso não tenha conseguido gravar os dados.

Então , você verifica , se a funcao retornar 1  , ele faz um select no banco trazendo as datas

```
function pegaUltimaData($pdo,$id){

        try{ 

            $sql = "SELECT * from suaTabela where id = $id";
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();
            if($stmt->rowCount() >= 1){
                $linha = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                return $linha;              
            }

        } catch (Exception $e){ 

            print "Ocorreu um erro ao tentar executar esta ação";
            echo  "Erro: Código: " . $e-> getCode() . " Mensagem: " . $e->getMessage();
        }

    }
```

Acima tem as 3 funçoes que acredito que você terá de usar , para fazer o select no banco voce verifica o retorno da funcao **inserirDatas**

Espero que possa ajudar.